# Split String into array in Linux

Tags: linux, split

I have the following variable IP_LIST

`The command echo $IP_LIST gives the result`

```
"10.36.107.121" "10.45.167.243" "10.12.154.43"`
```

`I am trying to store the result into an array using the command`

```
myarray=(`echo $IP_LIST | tr ' ' ' '`)
```

`But on the command echo $myarray I am getting the result`

```
"10.36.107.121"
```

Whats the possible error

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `tr`?

Comment: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/bash-split-string-into-array-linux/.   This tells me that tr is used to split strings

Comment: `Whats the possible error` There's no error and everything is working as it should. Did you expect something different to be printed out? ` This tells me that tr is used to split strings –` No, that is not what is says. On that site `tr` is used to replace `,` with a space. There's no point in changing space into a space... `tr ' ' ' '` is useless. Just `myarray=($IP_LIST)`

Answer (score 2):

`echo "${myarray[@]}"` will print out the full array, instead of only the first element. You build the array correctly, but the echo statement was wrong.

cfr how to use arrays and specific indexes [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/bash-arrays)